# locked out of my server Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I was connected to my server. i edited the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and added 
`----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
at the start of the public key and 
`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
at the end of the public key. I mistakenly lost connection to the host and now despite having id_rsa file, i am not able to connect to the host.
`ssh -i /home/me/id_rsa root@ip`
 It is showing me: 
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/me/id_rsa':`
`root@ip: Permission denied (publickey).`
How do I fix this? How do I connect the the server?

Comment: Do you have some user account to log into? It is weird to use just root (in fact often root login from ssh are disabled, for reasons). Else you should check to get console access to the machine (or some emergency reboot on a rescue disk, where you can mount and correct your files). It depends on your provider

Comment: I used to log in using root and it worked always. It is just now that after the edit to `authorized_keys` file i am not able to log in.

Comment: Note: it worked, but you should not log with root. In any case the best practices are not relevant to this question. You should find an alternate way to log (console, remote console, remote rescue access, etc.). And if you are working on remote machines: you must have a second way (for such cases, and never logout until you are sure you can log in again: change of configuration and updates: I learn them on hard way).

Comment: Why would you edit the file that permits your root login!? You will have to find a different way to log in as you have broken this one. A rescue environment or maybe you have a non-root login you can use, that allows you to become root via sudo or su

Comment: Why edit something that works? And why put stuff that clearly talks about a *private key* to a field you seem to know should contain a *public key*.

Comment: Don't log in as root. Proper Unix hygiene dictates that you should log in as yourself, and sudo as necessary. People who spend their day logged in as root are just begging for disaster.

Answer (score 3):

> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and added
> ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

`autorized_keys` is very clearly for the *public* key fingerprints that should have access. You added your private key, and  that doesn't fit the sense nor the format of that file at all. This has two consequences:

1. You broke the file, making it unparseable to SSH
2. You copied your private key, which should never leave your control, to a server somewhere else. We call this state *compromised*, and if you used it (or rather, its matching public key) elsewhere already, you now need to go there and remove access to them.

> How do I fix this? How do I connect the the server?

You simply can't via SSH anymore, unless there's a password set and you know it. This is good: you locked the front door to your house. Now it's closed.

Whether there's another way to connect to your server is something that we can't tell you. For example, you might not be the only admin, and another admin might still have access through their user account (seeing you broke SSH login for `root`).

If this is a cloud server, the usual course of action here would be to your management console, download a backup image of your server, use that as template / reference to provision a new VM, with which you replace the inaccessible one.

Comment: I did not add my private key in that file. My public key is still in that file. Its just that the key is surrounded by the texts what declare RSA PRIVATE key.

Comment: @HuzaifaMalik that makes … even less sense? Well, the good news is you didn't compromise your own private key, but you still locked yourself out of your server.

Answer (score -1):

I used the Provider's Management console to log in to the server system. I had created a backup of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` before making any change to the file which then i replaced with the original file and then my connection was established.

Comment: It's good to hear that you got access to your server again. And now you've hopefully learned to be a little more careful when messing with things that can affect your ability to log in (I learned that ~25 years ago when I changed the firewall of a host from home and had to access it physically the next day)

Comment: Sounds like this should be a comment rather than an answer.